# Why does my title text disappear when moving button closer to title?

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter

I created a start button for my program to begin the hangman game. Therefore, I also wanted to add a title right on top of my "Start" button. However, when the title is too close to the button, the button disappears like so:

[image: Title Disappears]

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.wm_title("HangMan")

canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=800)
canvas.pack()

title = canvas.create_text(400, 100, font=("Times New Roman", 20))
canvas.itemconfig(title, text="WELCOME")


#Creates the pole
def startgame():
    b1.destroy()
    a = canvas.create_rectangle(550,50,550,350,fill = "black")
    b = canvas.create_rectangle(350,50,550,50,fill = "black")
    c = canvas.create_rectangle(350,50,350,90,fill = "black")

b1 = Button(canvas, text="Start Game", width=30, height=20, command=startgame)
canvas.create_window(400, 200, window = b1)

def callback():
    result = e1.get()
    text2 = canvas.create_text(600, 20, anchor = "nw")
    canvas.itemconfig(text2, text = "Player Name: " + result)

e1 = Entry(canvas)
b2 = Button(canvas, text="Enter", width=10,command=callback)


canvas.create_window(250, 350, window = e1)
canvas.create_window(400, 350, window = b2)


e1.delete(0,END)
e1.insert(0, "Enter your name")

#Creates man
#d = canvas.create_oval(325, 90, 375, 140, outline = "black") #head
#e = canvas.create_line(350, 140, 350, 230, fill = "black") #neck and torso
#f = canvas.create_line(300, 125, 350, 175, fill = "black") #left arm
#g = canvas.create_line(400, 125, 350, 175, fill = "black") #right arm
#h = canvas.create_line(350, 230, 310, 300, fill = "black") #left leg
#i = canvas.create_line(350, 230, 390, 300, fill = "black") #right leg


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was able to solve this problem by taking out the height of the start button. Glad I was able to solve though :D

```
b2 = Button(canvas, text="Enter", width=10,command=callback)
```